# write pyspark dataframe to csv with out outer quotes

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.3

I have a dataframe with a single column as below. I am using pyspark version 2.3 to write to csv.

```
18391860-bb33-11e6-a12d-0050569d8a5c,48,24,44,31,47,162,227,0,37,30,28
18391310-bc74-11e5-9049-005056b996a7,37,0,48,25,72,28,24,44,31,52,27,30,4
```

In default the output for the code is

```
df.select('RESULT').write.csv(path)
```

```
"18391860-bb33-11e6-a12d-0050569d8a5c,48,24,44,31,47,162,227,0,37,30,28"
"18391310-bc74-11e5-9049-005056b996a7,37,0,48,25,72,28,24,44,31,52,27,30,4"
```

How can I remove the outer quotes? I have tried option('quoteAll','false') and option('quote',None) which did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try writing with a `|` separator. The default is `,` which conflicts with your content that contains commas.

```
df.select('RESULT').write.csv(path, sep="|")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `spark.write.text`:

```
df.select('RESULT').write.text(path)
```